# Your payment will arrive in 3-5 days

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I have a website (in development) which is using paypal (sandbox) to accept payments. I've setup a few sandbox users so I can test what happens when payments are send from my country and some foreign countries.

I've noticed that when setting up users with certain foreign countries, after making a payment, the foreign sandbox account gets a message saying "you're payment will arrive in 3-5 days". But the payment happens instantly in the sandbox account.

Why is that, is that just a sandbox thing? What I am asking is, when I go live, and if the user gets such a message, and if it does take 3-5 days for the payment to arrive, will paypal push the payment through to my ipn page as and when the payment happens, i.e. 3-5 days later?

I'm assuming that because I am using the paypal sandbox, they just display the 3-5 day message and push the details to my ipn page straight away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any time you get a payment that is pending for any reason you'll get an IPN at that time with a payment_status of Pending.  When the status changes you will get another IPN with the updated status.

Comment: Is it possible to test this with sandbox accounts?

Comment: Yes, if you have IPN configured in the sandbox seller account it will send notifications just like the live server would.  You can't speed it up, though.  You could setup the seller account so that you have to accept all payments manually.  That way when you do the transaction you'll get an IPN with payment pending status, and then when you manually accept the payment from within the account it should trigger the additional IPN.

Comment: I can't seem to find the option you mentioned.  The option in the sandbox so I can set the sellers account to manually accept all payments instead of automatically.

Comment: Look for Fraud Management Filters or Risk Controls under the PayPal account profile.

Comment: Or alternatively, click 'Profile' under https://developer.paypal.com/ > Applications > Sandbox accounts and toggle 'Payment review' to 'On'. This will force all newly received transactions to automatically enter into a 'Pending' state. Once you're ready to release the transactions (and thus complete them), simply toggle 'Payment review' back off.